"Could not load source" remote debugging kubernetes pod with dlv go debugger
I am using remote debugging with VSCode to connect to a Kubernetes go pod. I was able to attach debugger, hit a breakpoint and step through code in the current go project that is loaded in VSCode. However, when I step into a function that is imported from a go project whose source is not in VSCode, I am not able to step through the code and see an error "Could not load source".. Could someone help me understand how I can configure the sources correctly ?
enter image description here
This the the launch.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "agent",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "port": 40000,
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        }
    ]
}

When I step into the function, I want the source to load correctly and step through the code from the imported packages.
